# AWS Route53 record to a server subdirectory

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I want to point a URL to 12.13.14.15/someDirectory/index.html

I currently use an A record to point to 12.13.14.15.

What kind of record type do I need to use in order to point to the path that I want?

I am aware of the method where you go through a S3 bucket for redirects... but this also shows the url/ip that I redirect to. So it is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately DNS records by nature point only to IP addresses (A type) or other DNS records (CNAME type). This is an issue with your web server configuration, not with Route53.

However, if you would like to have a record set point to a subdirectory of your webserver, you can use the hostname configuration of your webserver (assuming you're not using S3 Static Website Hosting, and an actual webserver in EC2 or wherever) to point to the subdirectory in question.